# Select only Max number (and recode max) and keep others blank in dataframe and recode with multiple conditions with multiple variables

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to select max number for rows within each group and recode that number as "Last" and keep other as blank (below dataframe: new variable name is "Z"). After that I want to create new variable with multiple conditions corresponding with other variables (below dataframe: new variable name is "X").

Dataframe is:

```
ID = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4)

Care = c("Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","No","Yes","No","Yes","No","No")
 
Y = c(1,2,3,4,1,2,1,2,3,1,2)

Z = c("", "", "", "Last","","Last","","","Last","","Last")

X = c("","","","Always","","Lost","","","Linked","","Never")

df <- data.frame(ID,Care,Y,Z,X)  
df
```

I am able to create Y using this code:

```
main <- df %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(Y = row_number())
```

But, I want to create new Variables "Z" and "X" in my dataframe. X would be if care is Yes in all rows within each group = "Always", if care is No in all rows within each group = Never, if care is Yes at earlier and No at the Last = "Lost", if care is Yes or No at earlier but Yes at the Last = "Linked"

Here I am able to create Z variable (still need to create X):

```
 main %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(Z=row_number()>=which.max(Y))
```

I have been struggling with this for awhile now. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy! :)
You can save that step of working with `which.max(Y)` and instead just compare `row_number()` against `n()` in each group.
Creating `Z` is just an easy `ifelse`-statement and what I assume caused you a little trouble in creating `X` can be solved with `case_when()` to work through the four cases you describe. First, check whether `all()` observations within the group hold true to your condition of being "Yes" or "No", then check the two "mixed" cases afterwards.

This is what you're looking for:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(
  ID = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4),
  Care = c("Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","No","Yes","No","Yes","No","No")
)

df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(
    Z = ifelse(row_number() == n(), "Last", ""),
    X = case_when(
      Z == "" ~ "",
      all(Care == "Yes") ~ "Always",
      all(Care == "No") ~ "Never",
      Care == "Yes" ~ "Linked",
      Care == "No" ~ "Lost"
    )
  )
```

Comment: Nice answer @alex_jwb90.  Two suggestions: (1) OP seems to want `Y`, which could just be `row_number()`, and (2) changing `Care` to boolean makes `X` assignment a little cleaner.  For example: df %>% mutate(Care = if_else(Care == "Yes", TRUE, FALSE)) %>% group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Y = row_number(),
         Z = if_else(Y == which.max(Y), "Last", ""),
         X = case_when(
           Z == "" ~ "",
           all(Care) ~ "Always",
           all(!Care) ~ "Never",
           Care ~ "Linked",
           !Care ~ "Lost"
         )
  )

Comment: @andrew_reece I just skipped `Y` because it merely seemed to be there as a (superfluous) intermediate step to find the last row by taking the slightly overcomplicated way of calculating `which.max(row_number))`. It wasn't mentioned itself by OP in their question. Secondly, I didn't want to tamper with their data in the df, although you are right that a logical vector seems more ... logical. I think with your comment, we have all variation gathered to help, but if OP specifically requests it, I'll happily add your suggestions to my post.

Comment: Loved it and both ways are awesome. Thank you so much @alex_jwb90 and andrew_reece.